# codeception run test with four processes

Tags: php, unit-testing, codeception

I am trying to run a codeception test, it will go to a checkout and place an order and the test needs to be run four times in parallel, so that if we have 3 of item in stock we cannot buy if three other 'clients' are in the checkout process, can you run 4 different instances of the test at the same time?

I am also curious if codeception can be threaded this way somehow

Comment: Could you give an example of your test, how many requests it involves?

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easier if you write two different unit tests for your case. One that checks that it is possible to place an order if the chosen product is in stock, and one unit test that checks that it isn't possible to place an order if it isn't in stock.

This way you can get direct feedback that placing an order based on the product stock will work as intended.

Did I understand your question correctly?

Comment: It's a test for when multiple people are in the checkout process, so when they come back from payment gateway, we can see what items are still in stock